Google One Tap on localhost - "Can't continue with google.com" and Network Error: ERR_FAILED
I'm implementing Google One Tap authentication in my Next.js application using the following code:
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default function GoogleOneTap() {
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeGoogleOneTap = () => {
      const clientId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;

      if (!clientId) {
        console.error("Missing Google Client ID");
        return;
      }

      if (window.google && window.google.accounts && window.google.accounts.id) {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: clientId,
          callback: async (response) => {
            if (!response || !response.credential) {
              console.error("No credential received from Google.");
              return;
            }

            try {
              await signIn("googleonetap", {
                credential: response.credential,
                redirect: true,
                callbackUrl: "/",
              });
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error during sign-in:", error);
            }
          },
        });

        google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
          if (notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
            console.warn("Google One Tap skipped:", notification.getSkippedReason());
          } else if (notification.isNotDisplayed()) {
            console.error("Google One Tap not displayed:", notification.getNotDisplayedReason());
          }
        });

        setIsInitialized(true);
      } else {
        console.error("Google One Tap library not loaded.");
      }
    };

    if (
      typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      !document.getElementById("google-one-tap-script")
    ) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.id = "google-one-tap-script";
      script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.onload = initializeGoogleOneTap;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else {
      initializeGoogleOneTap();
    }
  }, []);

  return <div id="oneTap"></div>;
}

When testing on localhost, I encounter the following issues:

Error Popup:

"Can't continue with google.com. Something went wrong."


Console Logs:

The fetch of the id assertion endpoint resulted in a network error: ERR_FAILED.

client:72 [GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with IdentityCredentialError: Error retrieving a token.




I have already:

Verified that NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID matches the Client ID in my Google Cloud Console.

Added http://localhost:3000 as an Authorized JavaScript Origin in the Google Cloud Console.

Checked that the https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client script is loaded without errors.


What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to test Google One Tap on localhost?
Environment Details:

Framework: Next.js

Auth Library: next-auth

Browser: Chrome


